# Inequality for a weighted bilinear form in Fourier variables

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, inequalities, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

Let $\phi:\Bbb R^d\setminus\{0\}\to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous and symmetric, i.e.,  $\phi(-\xi)=\phi(\xi)$. Let $F:\Bbb R\to[0,\infty)$ be increasing and $L-$Lipschitz with $F(0)=0$.
Consider the space  $ H^\phi(\Bbb R^d)=\{u\in L^2(\Bbb R^d)\,:\, \langle u,u\rangle_\phi<\infty\}$ where we define
\begin{align*}
\langle u,v\rangle_\phi= 
\int_{\Bbb R^d}\widehat{u}(\xi), \overline{\widehat{v}(\xi)}\phi(\xi)d \xi.
\end{align*}
I would like to show (or disprove) that  for $u\in H^\phi(\Bbb R^d)$ we have
\begin{align*}
0\leq \langle F\circ u, u\rangle_\phi\leq L\langle u, u\rangle_\phi. 
\end{align*}

The intuition behind this inequality is that it is true in the particular case $\phi(\xi)=|\xi|^{2s}, s\in (0,1)$.  Indeed, $H^\phi(\Bbb R^d)= H^{s}(\Bbb R^d)$ and it can be shown that
\begin{align*}
\langle u,v\rangle_\phi= \int_{\Bbb R^d}\widehat{u}(\xi), \overline{\widehat{v}(\xi)}\phi(\xi)d \xi= 
c_s\iint_{\Bbb R^d\Bbb R^d} (u(x)-u(y))(v(x)-v(y))|x-y|^{-d-2s}d yd x.
\end{align*}
Since $F$ is increasing and Lipschitz we have
\begin{align*}
0\leq  (u(x)-u(y))(F\circ u(x)-F\circ u(y))\leq L (u(x)-u(y))^2. 
\end{align*}
From this, it follows that
\begin{align*}
\langle F\circ u, u\rangle_\phi\leq L\langle u, u\rangle_\phi. 
\end{align*}
The inequality can also be easily shown when $\phi=1$ and $\phi(\xi)=|\xi|^2$.

Any comment or reference regarding this type of inequality is welcome.